# why does this code always go to last record instead of locating the one highlighted in the DBCtrlGrid?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am using SQLite3 in a Delphi VCL app.

For some reason, some child forms show up correctly with the correct record when a button is clicked from the master form.  But this does not perform correctly, as well as several other similar code snippets in my application.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnAddApptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Editing :=  True;
  MMData.appts.Locate('apptID', IntToStr(MMData.apptsQry.FieldByName('apptID').AsInteger), []);
  MMData.appts.Edit;
  frmAppts.ShowModal;
end;
```

I have added `Editing`, `Adding` as `Boolean` variables under `public` and when the child form closes, they are set back to `false`.

I have googled and code seems to suggest it is written correctly, but still does not work as written. It always goes to the last record.  I have even simply wrote it like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnAddApptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MMData.Appts.Edit;
  MMData.Appts.Locate('apptID', MMData.apptQry.FieldbyName('apptID').AsString, []);
  frmAppts.ShowModal;
end;
```

And that doesn't work.  The `TDBCtrlGrid` is populated with the results of the query, but will look for the selected record in the `appts` table. It is supposed to return the record in the `appts` table that matches the `apptID` in the `apptsQry`.

Comment: _why does this code always go to last record_ No, this isn't what the code you've shown is doing. The code either finds a record and makes it active (`Locate` returns true) or doesn't change active record (`Locate` returns false). So the first thing to check is the result of `Locate` function.

Comment: @BrakNicku The code is supposed to locate THAT record matching the apptID and then bring up a form containing that record displayed.  What other way would I check the result of the Locate function?

Comment: @KBoykin Locate method returns boolean result to indicate whether the record was found or not. So you should check the result of this function to then determine whether you show form with more details from this record or notify user that no such record exists.

Comment: I don't understand.  I know Locate finds a record or it doesn't.  I have the exact code snippet in another part of the app that works just fine for another table.  It finds the record, sets the table to Edit, and then brings up the form at the record it found.  Could I have a corrupt part of the code I previously entered then?